# Error while Deploying Kafka Connect in Distributed Mode

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I am trying to deploy my confluent Kafka Connect for S3 in a distributed mode. But I am encountering the following error :-

```
(org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel) [qtp1620643420-22]
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: javax.ws.rs.core.UriBuilder.uri(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljavax/ws/rs/core/UriBuilder;
at javax.ws.rs.core.UriBuilder.fromUri(UriBuilder.java:96)
at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:275)
at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:205)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:852)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:544)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:233)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:1581)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:233)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1307)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:188)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:482)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:1549)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:186)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1204)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:221)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.StatisticsHandler.handle(StatisticsHandler.java:173)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:127)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:494)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:374)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:268)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:311)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:103)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$2.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:117)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.runTask(EatWhatYouKill.java:336)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.doProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:313)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.tryProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:171)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.produce(EatWhatYouKill.java:135)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:782)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$Runner.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:918)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

I can see the following version of **javax.ws.rs-api-2.1.1.jar** available in lib folder still it does not solve the issue. I tried importing glassfish jars but that didn't helped too.

Not sure what is the issue has anyone faced this issue can help me ?

Version which I am using

**Confluent Kafka S3 Connect version - 5.5.1**

Comment: Why are you showing Maven dependencies? Connect server doesn't need Maven and shouldn't be included in a separate Java app

Comment: it was what I tried to root out the error ... hoping that providing this dependency might resolve the issue but it didn't. I will edit it accordingly

Comment: But what are you adding the dependency to? You should not edit any JAR files. What version of Kafka or Confluent Platform are you using (not the Connector)? And what version of Java?

Comment: I am using Kafka 2.4.0, java will be 1.8. 
So I am trying to deploy it in docker container. The dependencies are for the custom plugin I am using with the connector. Hope this clears things for you.

Comment: Sorry, still not understanding. There's already pre-built Connect docker images, and you should not modify its dependencies. To add S3 connector, you can use `confluent-hub` cli